# Deno Typescript Cannot Find Server Dependency Injection

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, deno

I'm currently experimenting with Deno and its testing capabilities. I wanted to build a local server and inject the serve function from the standard library into my class. Currently, I run `deno test --allow-all` and get the error:

```js
error: TS2304 [ERROR]: Cannot find name 'Server'.
  runningServer: Server;
```

I've followed a pattern suggest on the Deno manual of moving my imports into a `deps.ts`

deps.ts

```js
export { assertEquals } from "https://deno.land/std/testing/asserts.ts";

export { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.88.0/http/server.ts";
```

main.ts

```js
import { assertEquals, serve } from "./deps.ts";
import { localServer } from "./local_server.ts";

Deno.test("can query a local server", async () => {
  const ls = new localServer("Hello World!", 8000, serve);
  ls.listen();
  const request = await fetch("http://0.0.0.0:8000/");
  const response = await request.text();
  assertEquals(response, "Hello World!");
  ls.destroy();
});
```

local_server.ts

```js
class localServer {
  runningServer: Server;
  response: string;
  port: number;
  constructor(
    response: string,
    port: number,
    makeServer: {
      (addr: string | Pick<Deno.ListenOptions, "port" | "hostname">): Server;
      (arg0: { port: number }): Server;
    },
  ) {
    this.response = response;
    this.port = port;
    this.runningServer = makeServer({ port: this.port });
  }

  async listen() {
    const body = this.response;
    for await (const req of this.runningServer) {
      req.respond({ body });
    }
  }

  destroy() {
    this.runningServer.close();
  }
}

export { localServer };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely `fetch("http://0.0.0.0:8000/")`. I guess you filled that IP address in because the server reported in the log that it is `listening on 0.0.0.0`. This  does not mean you can query it on that address, `0.0.0.0` is the placeholder for any IPv4 address and thus not a valid IP address for querying.

Use `localhost`, `::1` or `127.0.0.1` or another valid IP address or hostname.

Comment: Even changing to localhost, I still get the error ```error: TS2304 [ERROR]: Cannot find name 'Server'.
  runningServer: Server;```